# Не проходит тест, ошибка No tests found matching Method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Делаю тест для метода удаления данных.

```
//MessageController.java
@RequestMapping(
        value = "api/message/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
    if (!messageService.delete(id)) {
        throw  new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

//messageServiceImpl.java
@Override
public boolean delete(Long id) {
    Message message = messageRepository.findOne(id);
    if (message == null) {
        throw  new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
    }
    messageRepository.delete(id);
    return true;
}
```

Сам метод работает, записи удаляет, делаю тест для сервиса

```
//messageServiceImplTest.java
@Mock
private MessageService messageService;
@InjectMocks
MessageServiceImp messageServiceImp;

public void delete() throws Exception {
    //prepare
    when(messageService.delete(ID)).thenReturn(true);
    //testing
    boolean testMessage = messageService.delete(ID);
    //validate
    verify(messageService).delete(ID);
}
```

И получаю ошибку 
*java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method delete*

Метод же есть, в чем дело?

Comment: вы тестируете сервис, а зачем показываете код контролера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нет аннотации `@Test` перед тестовым методом

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил. Метод контроллера привел наверняка )

Comment: @SergeiR а зачем у вас 2 мока? по идее должен быть один мок - MessageService.

Comment: Я уже переделываю, понял что один лишний, изучаю тему тестирования.

Answer (score 0):

Еще подобная ошибка бывает из-за Gradle фичи [Build Cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html).

Решение - удалить каталоги `build` и `out` в корне проекта и попробовать снова.